# trying to install SQL 2008 on Windows 2008 server R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql, installation

I was trying to install MSSQL 2008 server on Windows 2008 server R2 Standard Machine, but I got this message:

> Program Compatibility Assistant, And that I should apply SQL server 2008 SP 1

I don't get it? Why doesn't it not work with this version I have? How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It will install however right after you install SQL Server 2008, you need to install Service Pack 1.

You can download [SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1 from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en).

Comment: okej thanks a lot, how do I get the updates for SQL server 2008??

Comment: You can download it off the net at: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

It does not work with the version you have because the version you have is terribly outdated and was released efore WIndows 2008 R2. Microsoft fixed compatibility issues in the service pack 1.

Given that by now there is service pack 2 released, and asignificant number of cumulative update packs - what exactly is the problem you have? DO you INSIST on running an old, outdated and buggy version of SQL Server?

Just install it, then apply the latest service pack and the latest CU.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anser,, How will I find the updates,, cause I was trying with windoww update,, and it could'nt find the updates.

Comment: SHould I download them one by one from windows download page or??

Comment: AFAIK, SP2 for SQL Server has not yet been released.

Comment: SP2 for SQL Server isn't slated to be released until Q3/2010. http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2010/02/12/sql-server-servicing-plans.aspx

Comment: Yes, sorry. The main point still stands - install, update latest SP, latest CU. NO reason not to.

Comment: It isn't that it's terribly outdated. It's just that SP1 addresses incompatibilities with the newest server-based operating system. We've seen this before with SQL Server 2000 and Windows Server 2003 / Vista.